# CSV.open(..) block does not execute, and ends immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am opening a CSV file for writing with the following code, as indicated in CSV documentation here (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html):

```
CSV.open( csv_file_out, 'wb' ) { |csv_line_out|

  #stuff happens here

}
```

the block does not execute, i.e. after the CSV.open command debugger goes directly to the end of block.

thinking "just in case", I try the same with IO modes `w+b` `wt` `w+t` `ab` `a+b`. I also tried creating the file before the in case there was a problem with opening it. nothing changes.

when I stop the debugger at the `CSV.open` line, I am able to execute a block manually and create a csv file myself. I can also create the file frmo the exact same command from console. But it won't work when executed in the server.

Any ideas on what's going on are very welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your server have write access for the output file and more importantly the directory?

Comment: yes it has. but i am runnign this not on my regular machine, but on a remote one which I haven't configured. will update here when I run it on my regular machine.

Comment: had a similar issue when an exception was raised because of encoding problems. writing the CSV suddenly stopped with nothing beeing printed to the terminal. i added a begin/rescue around it to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the {} brackets before your |csv_line_out|

Answer (score -1):

Your trying to iterate sth. (the files content) that does not exist so its logical that it ends imediatly! Try it this way:

```
CSV.open(csv_file_out, "wb") do |csv|
     csv << [column1, column2,...]
end
```

Comment: that is what I am currently doing: the differences I see between your code and mine are:

1. `|csv_line_out|` vs. `|csv|` 
2. double quotes vs single.

where you see `#stuff happens here` I am adding elements to the `|csv_line_out|`. this still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: This duplicates the op's question almost exactly, without any explanation.